# i can't restore cart data from database with Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Tags: php, database, laravel, e-commerce, laravel-5.5

i'm using Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart package and i made some editing on shoppingcart tabel when i migrate it and added like this

```
    Schema::create(config('cart.database.table'), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('identifier');
        $table->integer('userId')->unsigned();
        $table->text('address');
        $table->string('instance');
        $table->longText('content');
        // $table->nullableTimestamps();
        $table->timestamps();



        $table->primary(['identifier', 'instance']);
        $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

and also edited the store method (added two pramaters to store $userId and $address) in Cart class like this

```
public function store($identifier, $address, $userId)
{
    $content = $this->getContent();

    if ($this->storedCartWithIdentifierExists($identifier)) {
        throw new CartAlreadyStoredException("A cart with identifier {$identifier} was already stored.");
    }

    $this->getConnection()->table($this->getTableName())->insert([
        'identifier' => $identifier,
        'address' => $address,
        'userId' => $userId,
        'instance' => $this->currentInstance(),
        'content' => serialize($content)
    ]);

    $this->events->fire('cart.stored');
}
```

and all work very well in a database but the problem is when I restoring data from a database with restore method that restoring with only one parameter ($identifier) it gives me nothing and when i dd(Cart::restore(Auth::user()->id)) it gives me "null" please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You've modified the `store` method to accept `$userId`, but you're saying the `restore` method doesn't work. You can fix this specific problem by also modifying `restore` to accept `$userId`, because you're passing it your user id, but it's checking it against the `idenfitier` column in the `shoppingcart` database.

However, this is still a bad idea. You should never modify a third-party package, because it will get overwritten with the next `composer update`.

A better solution would be to simply use the `$identifer` to store the `Auth::user()->id`. If you need to store multiple carts per user, you can use the wishlist feature of this package. As a final resort, you can simply concatenate the id with the identifier, for eg. `'firstcart'+userId` and `'secondcart'+userId`.